# Mouseover Show popups - Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: forms, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have created a stacked canvas in Oracle Forms 10g.Also I have 2 buttons that on click perform show or hide functions on the stacked canvas.The stacked canvas is placed on top of a content canvas.

Now I plan to implement the same function on mouseover. How can I achieve the same.I would be using a number of icons in the content canvas.On mouse over on the icons a popup window will open that will have the contents of individual stacked canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `WHEN-MOUSE-ENTER` or a `WHEN-MOUSE-LEAVE` trigger for each of the icons and include a `show_canvas()` call to show the stacked canvas